# What's the difference between two jQuery selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, event-binding

I've seen these two different ways of binding a click event to an element but I don't understand the difference.

```
$('#cool-thing').on('click', function() {
  alert('This works!');
});

$(document).on('click', '#cool-thing', function() {
  alert('This works!');
});
```

They both produce the alert when the `#cool-thing` element is clicked, so is there a significant difference between the two or just a different way of doing the same thing?

Comment: YES, you might need read this event delegation https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 2):

Second option is event delegation, where `#cool-thing` may not exist in `DOM` when event attached, though may be dynamically appended to `document`  during current browsing session. `#cool-thing` parent element could also be used.

First option is where `#cool-thing` exists in `DOM`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to those who answered my question. Both answers were super helpful.

To help myself understand your answers, I was playing around with this in a Fiddle. I thought I'd share the Fiddle as an answer as well to hopefully help anybody else understand this, in case you're like me and only learn through visual examples.

https://jsfiddle.net/zf3g22um/2/

#### HTML

```
<button id="add-reg-bound-element">Add Regularly-Bound Element</button>
<button id="add-doc-bound-element">Add Document-Bound Element</button>
```

#### CSS

```
.reg-bound-element, .doc-bound-element {
  font: 600 14px sans-serif;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
}

.reg-bound-element {
  background-color: #BBB;

  &:before {
    content: 'Regularly-Bound Element';
  }
}

.doc-bound-element {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;

  &:before {
    content: 'Document-Bound Element';
  }
}
```

#### JS

```
//////////////////////////
// REGULARLY BOUND ELEMENT
//////////////////////////
$('#add-reg-bound-element').on('click', function() {
  $('html').append('<div class="reg-bound-element"></div>');
});

$('.reg-bound-element').on('click', function() {
  alert('Regular binding works!');
});

/////////////////////////
// DOCUMENT BOUND ELEMENT
/////////////////////////
$('#add-doc-bound-element').on('click', function() {
  $('html').append('<div class="doc-bound-element"></div>');
});

$(document).on('click', '.doc-bound-element', function() {
  alert('Document binding works!');
});
```